# how do you find the location of each city on the map and calculate its coordinates on processing?

Tags: processing

I have an image of map loaded into my code, also have a cvs file with the list of citys and their population, how do I get each city to show their population?

I have the following code for the table

```
for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {
int No = row.getInt("No");
String City = row.getString("City");
String 1991 = row.getString("1991");
String 2001 = row.getString("2001");
String 2011 = row.getString("2011");
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with the the library JAVE? Beyond that, your question is much too vague. We don't know your image and we don't know what sort of data you have access to. You could perhaps do something sophisticated with mapping GPS coordinates to pixels. On the other hand, maybe the best you can reasonable do is to manually assemble a list of pixel locations. Your question can't be meaningfully answered based on the little that you have communicated.

Comment: If you're image is a vector based .svg file you and it had layer names that matched the City name for the shape that could work. Check out [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Processing_%28programming_language%29&oldid=851680814#United_States_presidential_election_map). If you have a raster image you will need the x,y pixel coordinate for each city. Once you have that you simply render the city / population / etc. using [`text()`](https://processing.org/reference/text_.html)

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you posted is incomplete.
Also bare in mind variable names can't start with digits (e.g. `String 1991`, `String 2001`, `String 2011` are all invalid)

If your data included [latitude (-90 degrees to 90 degrees) / longitude coordinates (-180 to 180 degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Latitude_and_longitude) you could [`map()`](https://processing.org/reference/map_.html) the sketch dimensions.

Let's assume your CSV table has columns labelled "latitude" and "longitude", you could do something like:

```
float lat = row.getFloat("latitude");
float lon = row.getFloat("longitude");

x = map(lat, 90.0, -90.0,   0, height);
y = map(lon, -180.0, 180.0, 0, width);
ellipse(x, y, 9 ,9);
```

If the data doesn't cover the whole globe you may choose to map a smaller range of lat/lon angles around the cities you know the CSV data is covering.